# Socket bind error in C (cannot assign requested address)

Tags: server, tcp

First of all, I did `gcc client.c -o output` and then run `./output`. After that I run `nc 127.0.0.1 -l 8000` and wrote something, for example: **HELLO WORLD!** and it is received on the client successfully.
Now there are multiple other devices running on the network. I changed the ip address to one of those devices running on the network, but I cannot bind the socket. I got the error `cannot assign requested address` while running `nc 192.168.10.10 -l 8000`.

I checked the device and ping the ip address, it's totally fine. What I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wait… you are trying to bind the address of a remote host with a local program?

Comment: Everything is on the same network.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is, those addresses are used to communicate with a **remote** host. That means a program physically running on that host. If you want a program (say, `nc`) to run on host 192.168.10.10, you must go to that computer, login there and start it there. Then you can walk to your original host and run your client.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I cannot run my programs physically on the host because of different reasons. What should I do to access the remote host? and bind the socket?

Comment: SSH into it? The point is, when your client connects to `someip` on `someport`, it means *“contact remote host with that address, and see if there is a server program over there listening on that port”*. So to test that it works, you must start the server program on the remote host.

Comment: As I said, the server program is already started on the remote host. I contacted the remote host with that address, but I'm receiving nothing after running "nc 192.168.10.10 8000". When I'm putting "-l" (nc 192.168.10.10 -l 8000) then I get this error "cannot assign requested address"

Comment: Oh you mean that the client should contact with the remote host and check if the server program is listening on that port or not ???

Comment: If the error comes from `nc`, why are you asking about some C client program?

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant .NET and Java tags.

Comment: The `-l` flags tells `nc` to act as a server (`-l` is short for “listen”). It is used for testing. If the server program is already started on the remote host, you don't need `nc` at all, just run your client.

Comment: Well I didn't mention in the question but also tried without running `nc`. But I'm getting nothing from the server. Can you please help me in understanding how to “*contact remote host with that address, and see if there is a server program over there listening on that port*”.